# Microwaving frozen tofu before marinating

Tags: vegetarian, vegan, tofu

I froze some tofu in order to get extra water out of it before marinating and cooking. I'd kind of like to get a start on the marinating process, but it's taking a while to thaw at room temperature - is it ok for me to put it in the microwave, or will this ruin the texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page http://www.ehow.com/how_6514671_change-texture-tofu.html
http://www.ehow.com/how_6514671_change-texture-tofu.html
freezing and micro waving will change the texture.

But it seems the author actually prefers the texture change...